# How to use RCurl to PUT a document into MarkLogic

Tags: r, curl, libcurl, marklogic, rcurl

I'm working on some  code that will take a dataframe, convert it into json and put it into a MarkLogic database.  Below is a curl command that successfully creates a document in MarkLogic;

```
curl --anyauth --user rest-writer:rest-writer -X PUT -d '{"content":"abc"}' 'http://localhost:8003/v1/documents?uri=/json/my.json&format=json
```

The below `RCurl` code attempts to create a document in MarkLogic but fails with; Error: Unauthorized

```
opts <- curlOptions(header = TRUE, userpwd = "rest-writer:rest-writer",httpauth = AUTH_DIGEST)
myURI <- "http://localhost:8003/v1/documents"
myURIput <- paste(myURI, "?uri=/json/myOne.json", sep="")
httpPUT(myURIput, '{"content": "Hello MarkLogic"', .opts = opts)
```

I took a step back and attempted to just get data from a MarkLogic database using `getURL()` from the `RCurl` package;

The below code works fine (opts and myURI are the same as above);

```
myURIget<- paste(myURI,"?uri=/json/myDud.json", sep="")
getURL(myURIget, .opts = opts)
```

I then attempted to use the httpGET function from `RCurl`;

```
httpGET(myURIget, .opts = opts)
```

But again, I get `Error: Unauthorized`

I've set some debug option in the r code;

```
debugfunction = d$update, verbose = TRUE
```

but the result are basically the same.

Any input is greatly appreciated

Comment: What's the full version string for MarkLogic?

Comment: The MarkLogic version is 7.0-2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the httr code that I'd use

```
library(httr)

PUT("http://localhost:8003/v1/documents",
  query = list(uri = "/json/myOne.json", format = "json"),
  body = list(content = "Hello MarkLogic"),
  encode = "json",
  authenticate("rest-writer", "rest-writer", "digest")
)
```

I'd also check that your server actually used `digest` auth, `basic` is more common.

Comment: This works.  I also got this to work with ML version 8.0-20140809. Thanks